# Validate Mobile number in php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mobile

I want to validate mobile number of 10 digits and also add a prefix of 0 when I enter into the database.

```
<?php

include ('database_connection.php');

$citystate = $_POST['citystate'];
$serviceprovider = $_POST['serviceprovider'];
$accept = $_POST['accept'];
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array(); //Declare An Array to store any error message 

    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        $mumbai = (in_array("mumbai", $_POST['checkbox']) ? 1 : 0);
        $pune = (in_array("pune", $_POST['checkbox']) ? 1 : 0);
        $banglore = (in_array("banglore", $_POST['checkbox']) ? 1 : 0);
        $mysore = (in_array("mysore", $_POST['checkbox']) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    if ($mumbai + $pune + $banglore + $mysore == 0) {
        $error[] = 'Please check atleast one SMS center';
    }

    if ($accept != 1) {
        $error[] = 'Please check terms ';
    }

    if (empty($_POST['mobileno'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a Mobile Number '; //add to array "error"
    }
    if (empty($_POST['mobileno'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a Mobile Number '; //add to array "error"
    } else {

        $mobile = $_POST['mobileno']; //else assign it a variable

        /* if( preg_match("^[0-9]{10}", $mobile) ){

          }

          else {

          $error[] = 'Your Mobile No is invalid  ';
          } */
    }
    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a First name '; //add to array "error"
    } else {
        $fname = $_POST['fname']; //else assign it a variable
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a Last name '; //add to array "error"
    } else {
        $lname = $_POST['lname']; //else assign it a variable
    }
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
            //regular expression for email validation
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST['passwd1'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['passwd1'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['passwd2'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Verify Your Password ';
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['passwd2'];
    }
    if ($_POST["passwd1"] != $_POST["passwd2"]) {
        $error[] = 'Password does not match';
    }

    if (empty($error)) { //send to Database if there's no error ' //If everything's OK...
        // Make sure the mobile no is available:
        $query_verify_mobileno = "SELECT * FROM userdtls WHERE mobileno = '$mobile'";
        $result_verify_mobileno = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_mobileno);
        if (!$result_verify_mobileno) {//if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_mobileno==false)
            echo ' Database Error Occured ';
        }

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_mobileno) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this number .
            // Create a unique  activation code:
            //$activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO userdtls ( mobileno, serviceprovider, pass,  fname, lname, email, citystate, MUM, PUN, BNG, MYS ) VALUES ( '" . $mobile . "', '" . $serviceprovider . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $fname . "', '" . $lname . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $citystate . "','" . $mumbai . "', '" . $pune . "', '" . $banglore . "', '" . $mysore . "'  )";
        }
    }
}
```

Now I get stuck in mobile number validation. I tried using regular expressions.

What I want to do is add a 10 digit phone number and make sure it is only digits or else give error and while entering the number to database I want to add a prefix to the mobile number of 0 so it should be like 0and10digitnumber

Comment: 'please help ' - is such language permitted by SO policy ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$phoneNumber = $_POST['mobileno'];

if(!empty($phoneNumber)) // phone number is not empty
{
    if(preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$phoneNumber)) // phone number is valid
    {
      $phoneNumber = '0' . $phoneNumber;

      // your other code here
    }
    else // phone number is not valid
    {
      echo 'Phone number invalid !';
    }
}
else // phone number is empty
{
  echo 'You must provid a phone number !';
}
```

Comment: is this right ? `if (empty($_POST['mobileno'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a Mobile Number ';//add to array "error"
    }
 
if(preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$mobile)){
  $mobile = '0' . $mobile;

  // your other code here
  else {
 $mobile = $_POST['mobileno'];//else assign it a variable
 }
}
else
{
  echo 'Phone number invalid !';
  
} `

Comment: I edited my post according to your comment (your code in the comment is hard to read because it is not formated)

Comment: this is what I am trying to do

Comment: `if (empty($_POST['mobileno'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a Mobile Number ';//add to array "error"
    }
   
 if(preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$mobile)){
  $mobile = '0' . $mobile;
  
 $mobile = $_POST['mobileno'];//else assign it a variable
 }
  // your other code here
else
{
 echo 'Phone number invalid !';
 }`

Comment: is there a way I can directly contact you as this thing is confusing and I cant send you proper code format. Please its very important thats why I am troubling you. Please I need a help

Comment: what if 10 digit mobile number string=0123456789 which is in real only 9 
it would be great if you compare logically with 
if(is_numeric($num)){if($num=>1000000000){}}

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most efficient and well-readable form would be to use the **libphonenumber** library from Google. **PHP fork** is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php). It can help you not only to validate number itself, but you can check country code with it or even know if some **number is valid for specific country** (this lib knows which number prefixes are valid for many countries). For example: `07700 900064` is valid GB number, but `09700 900064` is not, even if they have **same length**.

Here's how I would validate mobile phone number in your app:

```
$phoneNumber = $_POST['mobileno'];
$countryCode="GB";

if (!empty($phoneNumber)) { // phone number is not empty
    $phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
    $mobileNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($phoneNumber, $countryCode);
    if ($phoneUtil->isValidNumber($mobileNumberProto)) { // phone number is valid
        //here you know that number is valid, let's try to format it without country code but with 0 at the beginning (national number format)
        $phoneNumber = $mobileNumberProto->format($mobileNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Phone number not valid!';
    }
} else {
    $error[] = 'You must provide a phone number!';
}
```

`$countryCode` is two chars **ISO 3166-1** code. You can check it for your country on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_codes:_A).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer because it gives me a better international solution but i have also posted a solution for country which support 10 digit numbers. +1 by me to you.

Answer (score 1):

For Indian Mobile Numbers it will be easiest

```
if(is_numeric($num)){
if($num>=1000000000 && $num<=9999999999){
$num="0".$num;
}
else{
echo "Invalid Mobile Number";
}
}
else{
echo "Hey Buddy mobile numbers are always in digits";
}
```

This idea struck me because of the willingness of finding easy and some short of mind because the number(1000000000 ) is the lowest numerical value(10 digits) and the number (9999999999) is a highest numerical value that can be used as a mobile number in India.
And one more thing code will run faster than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a regular expression like:

```
if( !preg_match("/^([0-1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $phone) ) {
   echo 'Please enter a valid phone number';
}
```

Comment: I used it .. It gives me error please enter valid phone number but still it gets registered and it gets the value in the database

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ereg("^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$", $mob)) { return false; }
```

Comment: Why would the first character be required to be 7, 8, or 9? Also, [ereg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) was deprecated 7 years ago and has been removed from the latest release of PHP.

Comment: this is only for indian mobile number validation

Comment: The question doesn't mention Indian mobile numbers, though. It just says "10 digits".

Answer (score 0):

Improving pravin tripathi's answer:

> `if(!ereg("^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$", $mob)) { return false; }`

since ereg() is deprecated, you could use

```
preg_match("/^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/i", $mobile_no)
```

This will help you validate a mobile number from India, since they are 10 digits and start with 7, 8 or 9 as of today. You could always change the pattern if new digits get introduced.