# Add prefix to mobile number in php before sending it to database

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please help me VALIDATE Mobile no in php form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786411/please-help-me-validate-mobile-no-in-php-form)

I got mobile number to validate but I am stuck at the prefix part.

```
if(empty($_POST['mobileno'])) // phone number is not empty
{
$error[] = 'Please enter mobile number';
} else {
if(preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$_POST['mobileno'])) // phone number is valid
{
  $mobile = $_POST['mobileno'];
  // your other code here
}
else // phone number is not valid
{
  $error[] = 'Phone number invalid !';
}
}
$prefix = 0;
$pmobile = $prefix . $mobile;
```

This is what I am trying to do for prefix. Is this right as I cant add the value 0 before the number.

Comment: And the problem you are having with this is...?

Comment: And what happens with this code? Is there any error?

Comment: A mobile number in which country?

Comment: Please do not repost questions.

Comment: Seems like  the only code you need now is adding the number  to your database?

Comment: if I enter any digit of any length it gets registered but gives me Phone number invalid ! error also..

Comment: Hey sorry @Pekka about the duplication but I changed the code and didnt know how to put in comments in my earlier post so made a refined new post

Comment: So you are using the code from the answer to your previous question, but you are not showing the modifications you have made to that code which are causing the problem and you have not accepted the previous answer? :S

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regular expressions?

```
 //check the first section is singular or multi, check area code between 0 and 9, check any additional integers
 $pattern = "[0|00]+[0-9]+[^\\s]";
 $phone_number = "000263712702879"; //international phone number
 if(preg_match($pattern, $phone_number)) {
      echo "this is a number";
 } else echo "this not a number";
```

Comment: I got the code working to check 10 digit number but how do I add prefix of 0 before adding to the database. Please check on top for $mobile I modified the code

Comment: @user1567321 use the `.=` operator in php, for example `$string = 12345;` and `$prefix = 0;`. Update the string with `$new_string = $prefix . $string;` or `$prefix .= $string;` (use either the appended or updated string to add to the database). Regards

Comment: ok slow down I am confused here . And where do I insert in the code. Like after checking the digits do I do that.

Comment: Yes, only add validated phone numbers to the database and ditch invalid numbers.

Comment: $prefix = 0;
$pmobile = $prefix . $mobile; This is what I did . No change it didnt do any thing

Comment: Are you sure, you have predefined `$mobile` with a value? (try printing it out).

Comment: i updated the code on top please check and let me know if its right ?

Comment: The reason it could be incorrect is because you're mobile is never being set. (The problem is with your regular expression).